# How to use variable inside python logger

Tags: python, logging, delta-live-tables

Is there any way to use variables in the python logger level instead of levels(error, info..)? I get event level from Delta Live Tables events

```
level_log = event.level // this is from Delta Live Tables Events
log_event.{level_log}(level, extra=extra) // is this possible? and how?

log_event.info(level, extra=extra) // I can use it like this, but I need to use a lot of statements
```

Comment: "//"  ist not a comment in Python

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Logger.log()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.log):

```
log_event.log(level, ..., extra=extra)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
log_event.{level_log}(level, extra=extra) // is this possible? and how?
```

Yes, you might get attributes dynamically via exploiting `getattr`, consider following example

```
import math
what = input("What constant value to show? ")
val = getattr(math, what)
print(val)
```

which will output `3.141592653589793` if you give `pi`, `6.283185307179586` if you give `tau` and `2.718281828459045` if you give `e`. Here I use built-in `math` module, but same function might be applied to instances of classes and classes themselves. Attributes which are callable might be then called consider following example

```
import math
trifunc = input("Value for which trigonometric function at 0 you want to know? ")
val = getattr(math, trifunc)(0)
print(val)
```

will output `0.0` if you give `sin`, `1.0` if you give `cos`, `0.0` if you give `tan` and so on